# Не удается отправить e-mail с локального хоста по SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

Сама по себе задача тривиальна, однако, никак не удается отправить сообщение по SMTP c локального компьютера (консольное приложение) на какой-то почтовый ящик. Пробовал и tcplistener и отключать антивирус, и брандмауэр (Win 8.1), но в любом случае результат один и тот же: "Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правилами доступа 127.0.0.1:25" (единственное, что при отключении антивируса сообщение ошибки немного меняется: "Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:25"). Плюс: "Сбой при отправке сообщения электронной почты", "Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером". В интернете вокруг да около ходят этой проблемы, но прямого ответа так и не нашел. Должен заметить, что при использовании в качестве сервера smtp mail.google, используя этот код с некоторыми изменениями все прекрасно работает.
Вот код:

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("somemail@gmail.com", "Y");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("some@mail.ru");
MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
m.Subject = "Тест";
m.Body = "<h2>Письмо</h2>";
m.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("localhost");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
try
{
smtp.Send(m);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: На то он и локальный хост, а не внешний. Чему вы удивляетесь? Какое отношение локалка имеет к внешнему миру?

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь в том, что правильно указали SMTP сервер гугла, и его порт. Также нужно указать данные для входа на почту, с которой идет отправка. Ниже пример кода.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 10000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com","password");

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("donotreply@domain.com", "sendtomyemail@domain.co.uk", "test", "test");
mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: Я как раз только добавил информацию в свой вопрос и вы уже ответили) Все верно. То, что вы описали я делал и все работает. Задача просто заключается в том, что я хочу использовать не гугл в качестве сервера, а свой же собственный компютер - localhost.То есть формирую письмо и отправляю без всяких посредников на конкретный ящик

Comment: @Stanislav1987 в таком случае у вас на 25 порту должен быть развернут свой собственный IIS SMTP сервер.  Убедитесь в том, что таковой сервис у Вас развернут и прослушивает 25 порт.

Comment: Окей, я попробую. То есть, фактически, без IIS не обойтись? Если, например, я захочу на хосте (win2012) установить свое приложение для отправки сообщений этому же хосту (в microsoft exchenge) все равно придется использовать IIS?

Comment: @Stanislav1987 верно понимаете, чтобы отправить почту куда-либо необходимо развернуть сервис, который умеет это делать. Это может быть не обязательно IIS, главное чтобы поддерживал протокол отправки SMTP. Просто так отправлять почту на порт, которого ничто не прослушивает - источник ошибки.

Comment: спасибо за оперативную помощь. Если возникнут вопросы я к вам тогда здесь в этой же ветке обращусь, но надеюсь все получится

Answer (score 1):

Поймите разницу почту рассылает сервер. А клиент подключается к серверу и отправляет команды. Вам нужен почтовый сервер с которого будет отсылаться письма.